# Can one convert a standalone SQL Server node to one node cluster?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We have a SQL Server on a physical machine and we'd like to migrate to a cluster.

I would like to know if it's possible to convert a standalone SQL Server to a one node cluster. If yes, can anyone recommend some good articles / resources that could be useful? Thanks!

Comment: Also see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260010/single-node-availability-group-is-it-possible

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know if it's possible to convert a standalone SQL Server to a one node cluster.

If you want to create a SQL Server Availability Group *only*, then you can do this as it's just adding in the failover clustering components and setting up the cluster.

If you want to create a Failover Cluster Instance (FCI) with SQL Server, then no you cannot do this as it's a completely different SQL Server installation type. You'll need to uninstall the local SQL instance and do a clustered install.